# save values from 2 classes in grails

Tags: mysql, grails, groovy

I have 2 classes named User.groovy and Employee.groovy and I used MYSQL to save the data. What I want is to create a new User account and save it to the User table and also save some of the data to Employee table. How can I do this? I've tried extending the user to Employee but the data only saved to User and not to Employee. But If I don't extend the User, the data is only saved to Employee. What should I do so that the data simultaneously saves to two database tables at the same time? Please help me.

Actually have this in my class user:

```
class User {

transient springSecurityService

String username
String password
boolean enabled
boolean accountExpired
boolean accountLocked
boolean passwordExpired
.....}
```

and employee:

```
class Employee {

String name
String email
String jobDesc
....}
```

So what should I do next? I'm sorry for this, I'm still starting to learn grails.

Comment: Did you understand what I mentioned in my answer?

Answer (score 2):

Grails paradigm (as far as scaffolding is concerned) is one form - one object. As long as you stick to this paradigm, you get all the goodies, such as input validation and error reporting for free (you may also consider using the Fields plugin here http://grails.org/plugin/fields).

However, sometimes you need to collect info and create two or more objects through single form. Usually this happens when you need to initiate new subscription and collect info for both subscription details (say, Subscription entity) and user info (User entity). This is where command objects come to rescue.

http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#commandObjects

So, instead of expanding/bending SubscriptionController or UserController (or UserController and EmployeeController, as per your example), you create SignUpController, which handles SignUpCommand object. The SignUpCommand object is not intended to be saved, it is used as a backing object for the SignUpController.create form. When it validates, you use the signUpCommand object data to initialize 2 domain objects (that is Subscription and User) and save these objects *individually within the same transaction*.

You can either delegate the save operation to a service say,

```
if (signUpCmd.validate()) {
    SignUpService.save(signUpCmd))
}
```

or create and save both objects right on the spot within controller

```
if (signUpCmd.validate()) {
    Subscription subscription = new Subscription(plan: signUpCmd.plan, ...)
    subscription.save()
    User user = new User(username: signUpCmd.username, ...)
    user.save()
}
```

it is mostly matter of taste and style.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling save() directly to your user instance, call a service class that saves both the user and the employee in one atomic operation. Like, for instance:

```
class UserController {

/*Injection of your service in the controller class*/
def userService
```

And then in the **save** action in this same controller:

```
userService.save(user) // userService.save(params)
```

And inside this service method you will extract the data (user or params, whatever floats your boat) you want to save in a different table as long as the usual user object.